# Cannot return a trait object of two traits

Tags: rust, esp-idf

I wrote a function that returns a Box of a trait object that is made of two traits.

```
fn get_gpio(pin: &u8) -> Result<Box<dyn InputOutputPin>, &'static str>{
    match pin {
        33 => Ok(Box::new(Peripherals::take().unwrap().pins.gpio33.into_input_output().unwrap())),
        32 => Ok(Box::new(Peripherals::take().unwrap().pins.gpio32.into_input_output().unwrap())),
        27 => Ok(Box::new(Peripherals::take().unwrap().pins.gpio27.into_input_output().unwrap())),
        26 => Ok(Box::new(Peripherals::take().unwrap().pins.gpio26.into_input_output().unwrap())),
        25 => Ok(Box::new(Peripherals::take().unwrap().pins.gpio25.into_input_output().unwrap())),
        _ => Err("Pin not configurable for dht")
    }
}
```

With the trait being:

```
trait InputOutputPin: InputPin<Error = EspError> + OutputPin<Error = EspError>{}
```

`InputPin` and `OutputPin` are traits defined by the [esp idf library](https://esp-rs.github.io/esp-idf-svc/esp_idf_hal/gpio/trait.OutputPin.html).

The only thing I am trying to do is to return a Gpio, but they are defined by [a macro](https://esp-rs.github.io/esp-idf-svc/src/esp_idf_hal/gpio.rs.html#1485) to be specific gpios. Because I want the function to return different gpios I cannot use the a specific return type like `Gpio1<InputOutput>`.

How can this be solved?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Are you wanting the pin to be configurable dynamically at run time?

Comment: Your trait should work as-is. Did you remember to implement `InputOutputPin`  (`impl<T: InputPin<Error = EspError> + OutputPin<Error = EspError>> InputOutputPin for T {}`)?

Comment: @Locke thanks that solved my problem.  I must have misunderstood a part of how this trait works. Can you point me to a keyword where I can learn about these supertraits, the rustbook is a bit short at this topic. 
Is there a cleaner way to archive what I want to do? 
Feel free to make this comment an answer so I can mark it as resolved.

Comment: Ok now of course when I want to derefence the Box to give it to [the Dht11::new](https://docs.rs/dht11/latest/dht11/index.html) I get the error ```doesn't have a size known at compile-time``` , is there a way to get the dereferenced Box to `::new`?
For reference: 
```let gpio = Self::get_gpio(pin).unwrap(); let dht = Dht11::new(*gpio);
```